# why does iterating with current.next works on linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying to skip every alternate node when i ran the below code and it ran.

```
def skip_alternate_node(head):
    current = head
    while current.next:
        current.next = current.next.next
    return current
```

I am not able to understand that why current.next is working when i am not even moving current.
In other words why `current.next = current.next.next` works when i am not doing `current = current.next`?
Is current.next is also a pointer on stack just like current which is pointing to a allocation on heap?

Comment: You're moving `current.next`.

Comment: You are modifying the next value of the node instead of changing current to a new node

Comment: You're modifying the list on every iteration, removing the old `current.next` from the list and replacing it with the node that follows.  It basically removes every node after `current`.

Comment: Python is not well suited as a language to the level of abstraction you're looking for. At any rate, a question like this is not on topic for Stack Overflow; this is not a discussion forum and thus not a place to get help with *understanding computer science*. You might try for example https://reddit.com/r/learnprogramming.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Which does leave me asking why it's named `skip_alternate_node`, when the actual effect is "remove all nodes after `head`".

Comment: *"is working"*: what is the code supposed to do? This code will turn your list to a list with just the head node in it. All other nodes will have been removed from it. Is that the intention of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `current` remains equal to `head`. The only thing that mutates is `current.next`, which will end up being `None`. So this code is an elaborate way to do:

```
head.next = None
return head
```

Your code returns the original `head` reference, but it has been mutated so that it has become the only node in the list. All other nodes are no longer reachable from `head`.

> I was trying to skip every alternate node

The code to alternate between *keeping* a node and *removing* a node, would need `current` to walk along the list. So add `current = current.next` to the loop's body, and put an extra safeguard in the `while` condition:

```
def skip_alternate_node(head):
    current = head
    while current and current.next:
        current.next = current.next.next
        current = current.next  #  <------ add this
    return head  # and return the original head reference
```

Answer (score 0):

`current.next` is a reference to another list node. Every node has a `next` attribute that points to the node after it. Therefore, `current.next.next` is the second element after the current element.

So each time through the loop, you change the current element's `next` link to point to the element after the next element. The loop will stop when it has gone past the last element of the list, so `current.next` will be `None`, and the list will just have the original head element.

The function shouldn't modify anything, and doesn't need a loop. It should just check if there's a next node. If there is, it should return the one after that.

```
def skip_alternate_node(head):
    return head.next and head.next.next
```

Comment: I don't think your alternate suggestion makes sense. I'm not 100% sure what `skip_alternate_node` is supposed to do, but I doubt it means just "get the second node" (though if my assumption that it's supposed to get every other node is correct, this would be a tool you could use to build such a generator by calling this function repeatedly, yielding each result until it came back `None`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Since his function returns a node, I was guessing this was what he really wants.